# how to develop a drop down menu in django based on a foreign key field in a model

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys, dropdown

I am developing a Django form to upload files. The form is based on a model(files). The model(files) has a foreign key field (repo_id). This repo_id is the primary key in the Repository model.

I want users to be able to choose which repo_id to put the file in. I need to insert a value to this field using a drop-down list in the form.

in the HTML template, the dropdown list is showing as "Repository object(repo_id)" [image: screen shot of the drop down list]

I have developed the two models (files and repository) in models.py, views.py, forms.py and HTML template following a tutorial. The form is working and it saves data in the database table as well.

I want to update the drop-down menu only to show indicator names in the repository model, not a repository object.

Here are my codes.

```
models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Repository(models.Model):
    source = models.TextField(db_column='source', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    indicator = models.TextField(db_column='indicator', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    key_aspect = models.TextField(db_column='key_aspect', blank=True, null=True) 
    category = models.TextField(db_column = 'category')
    table_id = models.TextField(db_column='table_id', blank=True, null=True)
    data_returning = models.TextField(db_column='data_returning', blank=True, null=True)
    data_source = models.TextField(db_column='data_source', blank=True, null=True)
    value = models.TextField(db_column='value', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    year = models.TextField(db_column='year', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    location = models.TextField(db_column='location', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.



class files(models.Model):
    repo_id = models.ForeignKey(Repository, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(db_column='username',max_length = 45)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_column = 'date')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/', db_column = 'file')
    username = models.CharField(db_column='username',max_length = 45)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.indicator_name

forms.py
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = files
    fields = ('username',  'file', 'repo_id')



views.py
@login_required
def file_upload(request):
     websiterepository = Repository
     #indicator_queryset = websiterepository.objects.filter(category = 'P').values_list('id','indicator')

    if request.method == 'POST':
         documentform = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

         if documentform.is_valid():
             documentform.save()
         return redirect('file_upload')
    else:
         form = DocumentForm()
         #documentform = DocumentForm(prefix = 'documentform')
         #searchform = SearchForm(indicator_queryset = indicator_queryset, prefix = 'searchform')
         #form = {'documentform':documentform, 'searchform':searchform}
         #return render(request, 'form_file_upload.html', form )
         return render(request, 'form_file_upload.html', {'form':form })
```

I know this is a lenthly post. I would be really grateful if you colud help me to figure this out.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the models to below code

```
class Repository(models.Model):
    source = models.TextField(db_column='source', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    indicator = models.TextField(db_column='indicator', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    key_aspect = models.TextField(db_column='key_aspect', blank=True, null=True) 
    category = models.TextField(db_column = 'category')
    table_id = models.TextField(db_column='table_id', blank=True, null=True)
    data_returning = models.TextField(db_column='data_returning', blank=True, null=True)
    data_source = models.TextField(db_column='data_source', blank=True, null=True)
    value = models.TextField(db_column='value', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    year = models.TextField(db_column='year', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    location = models.TextField(db_column='location', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __str__(self):
       return self.indicator
```

If you want model to return field value , you have to define a self function or else it will return the respective object .